# How should I handle useless answers on bountied questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags, bounties, low-quality-posts

Most of the times, when I start a bounty on a question without any answer for a long time, I got several useless answers.

Sometimes these are off-topic "spam" and contain a solution which is not working, but the poster is unable to fix it. In these cases at least an answer is present, so I need to reward the bounty for something which isn't a working solution.

I flag the answer as "very low quality", but sometimes it isn't deleted by moderator, so it is considered as a real answer and reputation points are gained undeservedly.

Comment: "so I need to reward the bounty for something which isn't a working solution." - You are not required to award a bounty.  if the answers are not helpful you should downvote them instead awarding a bounty to an unhelpful answer.

Answer (score 10):

> In these cases at least an answer is present, so I need to reward bounty for something which isn't a working solution.

No, you don't. You can just let the bounty expire and it will not be awarded, *unless* the answer was posted while the bounty was active and has a score of +2 or higher. In that case, it will get half the bounty amount.

> I flag answer as "very low quality", but sometimes it isn't deleted by moderator

That's because answers which attempt to answer the question but do not work should be *downvoted*, not necessarily deleted. That flag is also only for posts that are *unsalvageably low-quality* and should be deleted, which these answers are not. They might inspire others to create a solution which does work.